# Why does MISRA-C ignore C's mandated unsigned-to-signed conversions?

Tags: c, misra

The C Standard mandates that values of unsigned types which rank below "int", and whose values are within the range of "int", are always promoted to "signed int" when used in expressions.  Thus, given something like:

```
uint8_t a,b;

if ((a-b) > (uint8_t)1) ...
```

the subtraction and comparison must behave as though all values are converted to
type `signed int`.  I'm working on a MISRA-C 2004 project, however, with a compiler that's supposed to validate code to that standard, and it appears that MISRA's rules, at least in the 2004 version, are oblivious to such standard promotions.

Of the following expressions, which ones should be valid in MISRA-C 2004, MISRA-C 2012, both, or neither:

```
if ((a-b) > (uint8_t)1) ...          // Accepted by the TI compiler
if ((uint8_t)(a-b) > (uint8_t)1) ... // Accepted by the TI compiler
if ((a-b) > 1u) ...                  // Accepted by the TI compiler
if ((a-b) > 1) ...                   // Rejected by the TI compiler
```

If the TI compiler is accurately reflecting what is required by the MISRA-C 2004 rules, it would seem like the group that wrote those rules expected that C's promotion rules would be different from what C89 required, since the form rejected by the compiler has the same semantics as the first one, while the third form the compiler accepts looks superficially like the first one but has different corner-case behavior, and the second form has yet another different behavior.

Changing all occurrences of uint8_t to uint16_t or uint32_t does not seem to affect which forms are accepted or rejected, but would cause the first acceptable form to have semantics which on some compilers would match the rejected form (as it did with uint8_t), but on other compilers would match the other two accepted forms (which would then have the same semantics as each other).

Is the TI compiler correctly interpreting the requirements of MISRA-2004 in accepting code whose behavior would vary among implementations, and rejecting code whose behavior (in the uint8_t case) would be consistent on all conforming implementations?  Have the rules changed in MISRA-C 2012 in a way that would affect the above expressions?

Also, if MISRA-C 2004 would require either pre-casting the operands to the expression or post-casting the result, but the compiler was erroneously accepting the first and third forms, which did neither, in what cases would such casts be required?  Does either the 2004 or 2012 edition allow the casts to be omitted in the cases where the authors of C rationale would expect that signedness shouldn't matter (e.g. thus allowing:

```
uint8_t a,b,c,d;
a=b-c+d;
```

because even though the expression adds a signed value (b+c) to an object of unsigned type, the result is coerced in such a way that will treat as equivalent all results that are congruent mod 256)?

Comment: That sounds like a compiler problem, not a MISRA problem. As I understand it, there is no such thing as a "MISRA compiler".

Comment: What specific compiler are you using, with what settings? What is the exact error or warning output?

Comment: It'TI's compiler for one of their controllers.  My question, though, is about what the rules allow or are intended to allow, rather than about what one particular compiler does.

Comment: MISRA C is a set of programming guidelines; it does not change how the actual C language behaves. I don't think MISRA C is actually relevant here. My guess is you're in one of the following situations: `int` is 8-bit, your compiler has a bug, or your real code has some crucial difference from your snippet.

Comment: @user2357112: There are compilers that support checking MISRA guidelines, and the error comes from that, so it’s kind of relevant?

Comment: In what sense is the compiler you're using a "MISRA compiler"? Do you mean that it's a C compiler that issues warnings for violations of MISRA guidelines? Does the generated code behave in a manner inconsistent with C standard semantics? And can you include the text of the diagnostic in the question?

Comment: @user2357112: The MISRA-C standard specifies that programs must meet certain criteria to be compliant.  The rules of MISRA-C say that implicit conversions between signed and unsigned types are forbidden, but it seems to assume that the left operand of `>` in  `(a-b) > 1` is unsigned.

Comment: @supercat: MISRA isn't what's saying the left operand is unsigned. Your compiler is what's saying the left operand is unsigned. Your compiler may have a bug, or for all we know, it may be right. You still haven't told us what compiler you're using, what platform you're targeting, what compiler options you've set, or what the actual error message is, and you haven't posted a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @user2357112: I don't have a copy of the actual MISRA rules (that would cost money) but based both on the behavior of TI's compiler and examples of code that seems to be compliant, MISRA forbids implicit conversions between signed and unsigned types but doesn't squawk at C's implicit conversions.  The question of whether `(a-b)>1` and/or `(a-b)>1u` are MISRA-compliant shouldn't depend upon a particular compiler.

Comment: Which MISRA-C version? Which rule is the tool complaining about? MISRA-C:2004 and MISRA-C:2012 are somewhat different here.

Comment: @Lundin: I've updated the question to indicate that it's MISRA-C 2004, using TI's compiler in their Code Composer Studio.

Comment: I'd expect `if (a > b + 1)` could have been used to if OP did not want wrap-around behavior and avoid the MISRA issues.

Comment: @chux: `(a > b+1u)` would be acceptable to the MISRA tool I'm using, but without the `u` suffix it wouldn't be.

Comment: I don't remember the exact details but IIRC MISRA-C:2004 only enforces u suffix when the constant is intentionally unsigned. Static analysers tend to warn against every single suffix in the code though, even when it doesn't matter. Most of the time the `u` is harmless, so it is easier just to spam it all over and get rid of both true and false positives.

Answer (score 3):

MISRA-C:2004 (old) and MISRA-C:2012 (current) are slightly different. The former had a concept called *underlying type*, which is the type an expression would have had if not for implicit type promotion (either by integer promotion or by usual arithmetic conversions).

This concept was refined in MISRA-C:2012 and replaced with *essential type*, which is rather a group of types between which implicit promotions are harmless. For example a conversion from `signed char` to `signed int` is not dangerous - both types belong to the *essentially signed* group.

> Did the group that wrote MISRA expect that C's promotion rules would be different from what C89 required, with the groups who wrote subsequent revisions then being unwilling to recognize the Standard-mandated behavior?

No, they expect the promotion rules to be as mandated by C89 and later, but recognize how dangerous those promotion rules are.

> I could understand (and actually applaud) a MISRA rule that required that arithmetic on unsigned types must immediately cast the result back to the same unsigned type in cases where the result would be used in a way where signedness or upper bits might matter [as with the above comparison].

This is indeed what both MISRA:s require, unless the implicit conversion happens to a type of same signedness. In your case you go from `uint8_t` to `int` which is not ok. To be MISRA-C:2004 compliant you can either cast back to the "underlying type" `(uint8_t)(a-b)`, or cast in advance to eliminate the implicit conversion entirely, for example: `(uint32_t)a - (uint32_t)b`.

In addition, you aren't allowed to `>` compare a signed operand with an unsigned. Meaning that you have two options to make the whole expression MISRA compliant:

```
if ( (uint8_t)(a-b) > 1u)
```

or

```
if ( (uint32_t)a - (uint32_t)b > 1u)
```

(You may have to add additional parenthesis to sate other MISRA rules)

> Is the intention of the rule that ((a-b) > 1) be considered unacceptable but ((a-b) > 1u) would be acceptable

Neither is acceptable, since `a-b` gives an implicit unsigned to signed conversion and it fails on that.

Otherwise, `(uint8_t)(a-b) > 1` would still not be ok, but `(uint8_t)(a-b) > 1u` would be fine.

---

EDIT after question update.

Side note: In addition to not allowing conversion to larger integer types of different signedness, MISRA-C:2004 10.1 does not allow implicit conversion to a different underlying type of operands in "complex expressions" either. Where "complex expression" is a MISRA-C:2004 term for everything that's not a constant expression, lvalue or return value of a function.

So there's actually multiple violations of 10.1 here.

Now if I get this right, then this is what the tool should say:

1. `if ((a-b) > (uint8_t)1)`. Not compliant. Integer promotion changes signedness of all operands to `-` and `>` both. Complex expression with promotion to different underlying type.
2. `if ((uint8_t)(a-b) > (uint8_t)1)`. Not compliant. Integer promotion changes signedness of operands to `>`. Complex expression with promotion to different underlying type. The left operand's sub-expression is compliant in itself, but not as part of a larger expression.
3. `if ((a-b) > 1u)`. Not compliant. Integer promotion changes signedness of operands to `-`. Complex expression with promotion to different underlying type.
4. `if ((a-b) > 1)`. Not compliant. Integer promotion changes signedness of operands to `-` and `>` both. Complex expression with promotion to different underlying type.

(Ironically, my old, crappy MISRA-C:2004 checker (LDRA) merrily accepts all 4 expressions. But that's definitely a broken tool.)

Now the reason why `if ( (uint8_t)(a-b) > 1u)` is compliant, is because there is a cast back to the underlying type and then from there the usual arithmetic conversions come in to save the day. `(uint8_t)(a-b)` will normally be integer promoted to `int` but usual arithmetic ensures it ends up `unsigned int`, which is the same signedness as the underlying type, `uint8_t`.

My conclusion is that the "TI checker" in the question is giving the wrong results.

As for the rationale behind these rules in MISRA, it is merely to ensure that there are never any unintended implicit type promotions. Programmers who are unaware of implicit promotions write bugs and should be educated. Programmers who write code that intentionally and silently depends on implicit promotions write unmaintainable code rot and should be fired.

For example an expression such as `a=b-c-d;` (I altered it slightly), signedness could matter plenty. Consider `b=0, c=255, d=2`. Was the intention then to exploit `uint8_t` unsigned wrap-around, or to perform the calculation on `signed int` (which is what will actually happen), or to perform the calculation on `unsigned int`? All 3 are possible intentions and they may give different results. In addition there's an implicit lvalue conversion here - intentional or not?

Comment: The Standard dictates that operands of type `uint8_t` are going to get implicitly promoted to `signed int`.  Such conversion is mandated to occur even if the expression which involves the short unsigned type gets cast or coerced back to an unsigned type.

Comment: Should a proper MISRA validation tool for both the 2004 and 2012 versions of MISRA squawk at `(a-b)>1u`?  Should they do so even if `a` and `b` were larger unsigned types which likely would not promote?

Comment: @supercat Yeah so MISRA-C has the concept of underlying type/essential type which is about casting back to the original type in some cases. `(a-b)>1u` is not ok because there is integer promotion that changes signedness in the sub-expression `(a-b)`. I think it is best if you get MISRA-C:2012 and read up on this yourself, they devote a whole chapter just to implicit promotions.

Comment: My present task is to make some changes to a MISRA-C 2004 project.  If some rules have been changed it would be useful to know what the old and new rules are.  If `a`, `b` are `uint8_t`, the behavior of `a-b > (uint8_t)1` [which my 2004 validator accepts] is defined by the C Standard as equivalent to `a-b > 1` [which it rejects], but different from `a-b > 1u` [which it accepts].  All of those are in turn different from `(uint8_t)(a-b) > 1u`.  I'll rework the question a bit to help improve it.

Comment: @supercat notes that "The Standard dictates that operands of type `uint8_t` are going to get implicitly promoted to `signed int`."  --  which idiot decided that implicitly promoting an unsigned to a signed was a good idea?

Comment: @supercat The main issue, that there should be no implicit conversions from signed to unsigned or vice versa, remains the same in 2004 and 2012. But 2012 is much clearer, since it works with groups of types rather than for example the exact type `uint8_t` (which in MISRA-C:2004 would be the "underlying type" here).

Comment: @Andrew Dennis Ritchie, probably. To counter one evil, namely integer overflow, he allowed another evil, implicit type promotion. And now we have two problems instead of one, since overflow bugs still occur.

Comment: @supercat Updated with my interpretation of MISRA-C:2004 10.1. There's actually a bit more to the rule than implicit change of signedness.

Comment: @Lundin: What would have avoided the issue would have been for C to have included two different kinds of unsigned type from the start: wrapping types which do not promote and coerce non-wrapping types to their size (operation on mixed-size wrapping types would be an error) and number types which eagerly promote.  If unsigned types are going to promote, it makes sense to have them promote to signed types in cases where that would affect defined behavior (it makes no sense to have a compiler for a 32-bit platform interpret something like `(u16a * u16b) & 0xFFFF` as an excuse to ignore...

Comment: ...any scenarios where the product would exceed 2147483647).  A sensible MISRA rule would be to treat operations like `>`, `/`, etc. as accepting infinite-precision operands and apply the rule requiring that the results of certain expressions be cast before conversion to larger types, but I don't think that's what my MISRA tool does.  If tool makers interpreted the rules as allowing that, perhaps the text of the rule was unclear.  Maybe that's why it was changed in 2012?

Comment: What would have been better would have been for C to have an 8 bit integer, rather than repurpose char, which added all sorts of complications for character handling!

Comment: Also, with regard to the form `(uint8_t)(a-b) > (uint8_t)1`, I would think the rules should allow that form, since the `>` will unambiguously behave in a fashion consistent with both operands being of type `uint8_t`.  Further, in a case like `a=b-c-d;`, signedness shouldn't matter on any remotely-normal implementation if all operands are the same unsigned type [for uint8_t, it shouldn't matter in any case] since the result will get mod-reduced to the original value's range.  See the C89 rationale for the cases where it could matter on sensible implementations.

Comment: @Andrew: And to have a separate "memory-chunk" type as well without a specified minimum size [so code targeting machines which can access units smaller than 8 bits could exploit that].

Comment: @Andrew: See my earlier comment "what would have avoided the issue".  A problem faced by the authors of the Standard is that even before the keyword `unsigned` was invented, there were platforms where `char` was naturally unsigned, and would promote to `int`, which would be the only sensible behavior if no `unsigned int` type existed, and by the time the Standard was written there were implementations that would treat `unsigned char` the same way as `char`.  To have forbidden implementations from behaving that way would have been a severe breaking change.  If the authors of the Standard...

Comment: ...had deprecated code where the behavior with existing small types would be affected by such a decision, but added new types whose behavior would be unambiguous, that would have made things cleaner and more portable going forward, but the authors of the Standard were unwilling to say any existing code was "bad".  Indeed, contrary to what some compiler writers seem to believe, even a finding that certain constructs invoke UB was not intended to suggest that code using them should be viewed as "defective", nor that quality implementations shouldn't try to support such code when practical.